# Mockito.anyList() with specific value

Tags: java, mockito

I have a test where I mock result of some service like this:

```
Mockito.when(service.getValuesByIds(Mockito.anyList()))
       .thenReturn(values);
```

And my question is there any possibility to mock a list which contains some specific value (don't care about other values in a list, but they exist too)?

Something probably like this:

```
Mockito.when(service.getValuesByIds(Mockito.anyList().containing(555)))
       .thenReturn(values);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [custom argument matchers](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers)

```
@Test
void shouldMatchValue() {
    ...    
    ArgumentMatcher<List<Integer>> matcher = new CustomMatcher(555);        
    Mockito.when(service.getValuesByIds(argThat(matcher)))).thenReturn(values);        
    ...
}

public class CustomMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<List<Integer>> {

    private final int expected;

    public CustomMatcher(int expected) {
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(List<Integer> myList) {
        // put logic here for example,
        return myList.contains(expected);
    }
}
```

As of Mockito 2.1.0 and up with Java 8 you can pass a lambda to `argThat` which is closer to your example -

```
when(service).getValuesByIds(argThat(myList -> myList.contains(555)).thenReturn(values);
```